# Python: function parameter combination validation

Tags: python, validation, parameters, arguments

Trying to validate function parameter combinations. Such that `()`, `(project)`, `(project,field)` and `(project,field,well)` are valid and every other combination (e.g. `(field)`) is not. If available, arguments will be strings otherwise defaults are None or empty string "". Currently doing poor man's bit mask check...

```
def make_thing(project=None, field=None, well=None):
    # check for valid p-f-w combinations
    check = (8 if project else 0) + (4 if field else 0) + (1 if well else 0)
    if check not in (0, 8, 8 + 4, 8 + 4 + 1):
        return None

    # continue to do work
```

Question: What is a proper **Pythonic** way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### First Suggestion

```
def make_thing(project=None, field=None, well=None):
    if (not project and field) or (not field and well):
        return

    # continue to do work
```

#### Second Suggestion

```
def make_thing(project=None, field=None, well=None):
    if (bool(project), bool(field), bool(well)) not in (
        (False, False, False),
        (True, False, False),
        (True, True, False),
        (True, True, True),
    ):
        return

    # continue to do work
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is difficult to reason about.. at least for me.

Comment: @k1m190r I guess so. A first suggestion may not be Pythonic. I add a second suggestion.

Comment: and to continue the craziness `itertools.combinations_with_replacement([True, False], 3)` ...